# connecting to host running ssh2 server using ssh client

Tags: ssh, openssl

I am trying to connect to a linux host( target_host)  running **sshd2** using a **ssh** client( client_host) ;While doing so I converted the pub key of client_host as

```
ssh-keygen -e -f id_rsa.pub > client_host_ssh2_id_rsa.pub
```

and copied **client_host_ssh2_id_rsa.pub**  to target_host.
However when i try to connect I get **"no hostkey alg"**

```
ssh user@target_host -v
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8a 11 Oct 2005
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to target [169.35.74.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 6.0.12.81 SSH  Tectia Server
debug1: no match: 6.0.12.81 SSH Tectia Server
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
no hostkey alg
```

Can someone please help me identify what am I missing here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).